# HTML video starts to download after several other images on the page have finished downloading

Tags: javascript, html, video

Sometimes the HTML video on the topmost portion of [my site](http://www.toda.com) doesn't run when user is visiting the site for the first time. This is due to the movie being loaded long after the other images files on the page have been downloaded. Until that point the request for the resource is not being sent as I can see through firebug's net extension.

Since the video is on the top of other images I want it to be downloaded *first* & quicker. In my HTML code as well, video is placed before the other images so why is the downloading of movie blocked for such long times ?

How should I fix this to make the movie load faster?

The movie size(of .mp4 version) is around 600Kb for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible solutions to your problem:

a) Use CSS `background-image` on an `inline-block` DIV instead of `<img>` elements. Background loading is run on lower priority thread(s) on almost all browsers. This way your video loading is very likely to get more priority.

b) In your `<img>` tags, do not specify the `src` attribute. Instead specify the image source in another attribute, say `isrc`. In your domReady callback, copy the `isrc` attribute to `src` for all images. i.e. something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('isrc')) {
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('isrc'));
    }
  });
});
```